# Remove white thin border from exported PNG from Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, png, borders

I have a branding logo saved as a PSD Photoshop file. I'm exporting it to the PNG format with relevant size, but the exported PNG image has a thin white border around the logo.

How can I remove this border to have only the transparent logo image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how you "export to PNG" within Photoshop. There is no such option. I'll assume you are simply using the Save for Web command....

In the Save for Web dialog, ensure there is no Matte color selected (on the top right side of the Save for Web window).

Comment: Thank you, it is what I was looking for. Previously I used 'Save as..' option instead of 'Save for Web' command.

Comment: @ReganMusic this is a 2013 answer -- Circa CS6.

Answer (score 2):

In the Save for web dialog,make sure Matte color none.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will upvote it when I have   enough reputation points :).